# How to display table data in reverse? (php)

Tags: php, image, reverse

I have simple code for displaying images. I created table with 4 columns (ID, location, capture, equence) and inserted there 18 records. My question is: how to display all records from table in reverse mode? I need to make that the last entry will be displayed first, and the first entry displayed last.

What I need: 18-1
What I have now: 1-18

I was searching for simple codes to do that, but notwing worked at all. So i'd be very grateful if someone will help me to solve that problem.

Heres the basic code of my display script:

---

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("martinidb1337") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klpgalerija") or die(mysql_error()); while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
}
```

---

Comment: "SQL tutorial" is likely a relevant search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use MySQL [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) clause for that,

```
SELECT * FROM klpgalerija ORDER BY id DESC
```

**Note**: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

So use either [`PDO`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893) or `MySQLi` (IMO PDO is way to go)

Answer (score 1):

Changed query from `"SELECT * FROM klpgalerija"` to `"SELECT * FROM klpgalerija ORDER BY ID DESC"`

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("martinidb1337") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klpgalerija ORDER BY ID DESC") or die(mysql_error()); while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
}
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated use PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: Thats strange. I was trying to do that couple of days ago, and that wont worked at all. Now i paste your code and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add an order by desc clause in your sql query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT klpgalerija.* FROM klpgalerija order by klpgalerija.ID desc") or die(mysql_error());
```