# How to display table content in reverse order?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I need to display table of contents from bottom to top. Since when a new row is inserted, it appears at bottom and when I access it using **mysqli_fetch_array** it shows the most recent inserted row at the bottom. The code is like this:

```
<?php
    $abc = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","members") or die(mysqli_error($abc));
    $select_query = "SELECT title, url, photographer, genere, timestamp FROM gallery";
    $select_query_result = mysqli_query($abc, $select_query) or die(mysqli_error($abc));
?>
```

And somewhere in html, this code appears.

```
<ol class="pictures">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query_result)) { ?>
        <li class="thumbnail" data-div="<?php echo $row['genere'] ?>,<?php echo $row['photographer'] ?>,<?php echo $row['title'] ?>,<?php echo $row['timestamp'] ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $row['url'] ?>)">
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ol>
```

So, what should I do to display it in reverse order so that I can get the most recent entry on top while displaying.

Comment: Order query results by some field, `timestamp` I suppose, or maybe `id`, if you have `id` field.

Comment: just use order by in query

Comment: at least try to google @Anynomous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display table data in reverse? (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976848/how-to-display-table-data-in-reverse-php)

Comment: Read [ask], do some research first. Your question's title is literally answered by the first Google hit.

Answer (score 2):

Simply order your SQL Query by using either

ORDER BY attribute ASC/DESC

So for example if you want the most recent entry on top, simply change your SQL query to:

```
"SELECT title, url, photographer, genere, timestamp FROM gallery ORDER BY timestamp desc"
```

And it should work. You can do this with any attribute you want. I recommend to do it with the primary key (ID) if you have one, but since you're not selecting it, you can do it with your timestamp too. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sorting-results.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use `Order By`:

```
<?php
        $abc = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","members") or die(mysqli_error($abc));
        $select_query = "SELECT title, url, photographer, genere, timestamp FROM gallery ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
        $select_query_result = mysqli_query($abc, $select_query) or die(mysqli_error($abc));
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Modify Your SQL Query

Use [ORDER BY](https://www.guru99.com/order-by-desc-and-asc.html)

```
SELECT title, url, photographer, genere, timestamp FROM gallery ORDER BY id DESC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want to use `ORDER BY`:

```
for($i = count($select_query_result), $i > 0; $i--) {
    // Actions
}
```